# Using Javascript to redirect to an anchor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a website that's mostly generated via PHP and uses the jQuery library (v1.11.1).  My problem is that I would like to link to anchor tags that are generated dynamically on separate pages.

For example, I have the following link on index.php?page=Home:

```
<A HREF="http://URLhere/index.php?page=ABC#firstItem"></a>
```

And on the page that's loaded when $_GET[page] == "ABC," I have the anchor:

```
<a name="firstItem"></a>
```

So far, so good.  But when I try to click the link, it redirects to the page without jumping to the anchor.  The same behaviour happens if I click Reload.  However, if I enter the URL directly into the browser window, it DOES jump to the anchor.

I've found that the problem goes away if I delete the "function detach()" from the jQuery file, but then some other libraries that I've loaded fail to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to be in the same location as the href to jump to the anchro, else do it in jQuery

Comment: How would I go about doing it in jQuery?

Comment: an anchor link that you generate just pass one parameter/variable value read that parameter value on index.php and depending on that variable do operation that you want